How to interpret the transfer function to determine if the filter is highpass or lowpass
A digital filter $y_t = x_t - a_1 x_{t-1}$ has the absolute value of its transfer function $\left| \mathscr{H}(z) \right|$ as $\left|z - a_1 \right|$. A Digital Signal Processing Primer says $z = -1$ makes the filter as lowpass.

Question
Why is it lowpass when $z=-1$? It looks to me the magnitude of the transfer function $\left| -1 - a_1 \right|$ at $ω = \pi$ is larger than $\left| 1 - a_1 \right|$ at $ω = 0$ given $z = e^{j\omega}$. If I am not mistaken, $e^{j\omega} = -1$ when $\omega = \pi$.
Is magnitude of transfer function larger at higher frequency $\omega =\pi$ than lower one $\omega=0$ not a highpass filter?

Filter Definition


Transfer Function Definition


This book uses unusual notation. Standard is to use $b_n$ for numerator coefficients and $a_n$ for denominator coefficients. This may lead to significant future confusion if you use different sources.

The term "lowpass" isn't strictly defined. It generally means that "below a certain frequency the transfer function is reasonably constant and above that frequency it's attenuated". The high pass being the opposite: "flat above the crossover frequency, attenuated below".
So the best way to determine whether something has a highpass or lowpass character (or neither) is to plot it and take a look.
If you have a zero at $z = -1$ your difference equation becomes
$$y[n] = 0.5*(x[n] + x[n-1])$$
and if you plot the magnitude of the transfer function it is indeed a lowpass filter. For a zero at $z=1$ the difference equation becomes
$$y[n] = 0.5*(x[n] - x[n-1])$$
which is a high pass.

